# intelliJ fails to resolve 0.13.9 compiler interface importing sbt project

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

Importing a project into intelliJ, I get:

```
SBT project import
            [warn]  [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.9!compiler-interface.jar:  (0ms)
```

Here's the import options I selected:

[image]

After the import everything works though.

I don't get this error in sbt when I clone the same project. What might it be? how do I avoid it?